# Using css to keep elements centered

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm dynamically adding select dropdowns with jquery into a div. I would like to begin with the div centered and then as the new dropdowns are added to move out from the center outwards.

Here is the CSS for the divs:

```
#pageMiddle{
    width:940px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    position:relative;
}
#searchBar{
background: red;
width:500px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#searchwrapper{
    width:850px;
background: blue;
}

#searchwrapper form {
 display:inline ; 
 margin: 0 auto;

}
```

and the actual HTML:

```
<div id="pageMiddle">
<div id="holder">
<div id="searchBar">
    <div id="searchwrapper">    
        <form name="search_input">
            I am looking for a      
            <div id="sBar1" style="display:inline;">
<select id="search_level" class="selectSearchBar" name="search_level">  
                <?php echo "<option>Level</option>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_level, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo "<option value=".$row['id'].">".$row['level']."</option>";
            }?>             
            </select>
                </div>
                <div id="sBar2" class="selectSearchBar"></div>
                <div id="sBar3" class="selectSearchBar"></div>
            tutor in 
<input type=text class="searchbox" id="location"  value="Location"/> 
    <input type=image src="images/search_icon.png "  class="searchbox_submit" name="searchbox_submit"  onclick="searchLocations()" value=""></form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are missing units on some of your widths, and you don't need `px` if the value is zero in your `margin`s

Comment: @TomPietrosanti - thanks - they are typos and are correct in the real script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/L6GDL/)?

Notice the blue section is centered in the red section. This was done with the table display, which allows something of indefinite size to be centered via automatic margins. Otherwise, it must be a block element *and* have a definite size.

```
#searchwrapper
{
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: however the problem now is that the . searchbox_submit button drops down to the next line whenever the new select element is added which is strange

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php echo "<option style="text-align:center;">Level</option>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_level, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo "<option value=".$row['id'].">".$row['level']."</option>";
        }?>
```

Let me know if this works please.

Comment: thanks for the input but this will only center the text - not the entire div, which is what I needed - have a look at Mike's reply above!